# If statement within an if statement

Tags: php

How do I put an if statement within an if statement? Right now it's like this;

```
<?php
if($var1===$var2)
{
if($condition1 > 0)
{
*lots of code here*
}
}
else
{
*lots of code here again*
}
}
?>
```

Meaning that I want $condition1 to be bigger than 0 IF $var1 does not match $var2. But as it stands I am duplicating the "lots of code part" so I just want to;

```
if($var1!=$var2){ -apply if statement- } 
*lots of code here*
if($var1!=$var2){ -close if statement- }
```

But how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$a = ($var1 === $var2);
$b = ($condition1 > 0);

if (!$a || $b)
{
*lots of code here*
}
?>
```

Comment: I want to place `if $condition1 > 0` above *lots of code here* IF the vars do not match. If the vars do match I want the `$condition1 > 0` statement to stay out.

Comment: It seems I made a mistake in my original example. My head's a mess, sorry for the confusion! It should be more clear now. I can't believe how badly I am screwing this thing up ^^

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I meant.

Answer (score 1):

You have the right way of combining two if statements. However, you want to run lots of code either when var1 equals var2 or when condition1 is bigger than 0. You can write that like this:

```
<?php
if ($var1===$var2 || $condition1 > 0)
{
    *lots of code here again*
}
?>
```

The `||` operator means 'or'.

Comment: But now it executes the code if the vars match OR if condition1 is bigger than 0. That's not what I want. I just want to place `$condition1 > 0` above *lots of code here* IF the vars match. If the vars do *not* match I simply want the `$condition1 > 0` statement to stay out.

Comment: Wait I got that backwards (-.-) I meant I want to place `if $condition1 > 0` above *lots of code here* IF the vars do *not* match. If the vars *do* match I want the `$condition1 > 0` statement to stay out.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe i don't get it but i'd do it like this:

```
if($var1 === $var2 || $condition1>0){

//lots of code here

}else{

}
```

EDIT - maybe you wan't this - it reads if var1 is equal to var 2 OR if var1 is not equal to var2 and condition1>0 do lots of code

```
if($var1 === $var2 || ($var1 !== $var2 && $condition1>0)){

//lots of code here

}else{


}
```

Comment: I want to place `if $condition1 > 0` above *lots of code here* IF the vars do not match. If the vars do match I want the `$condition1 > 0` statement to stay out.

Comment: Thanks to you and the others for responding, figured it out now. This is like, the main reason coding is so hard for me, with all the ifs and buts I get confused so bad it's surreal >.>